How to add labels without markers and in place of them (left aligned merging label and marker) in legends
I want to add some parameters with their values into legends, which have no markers and must be left aligned placing on top of other markers positions (i.e. in a column with other markers). It will be done with using titling them in legends if we have just one columnar legend. The problem arises when two or more columns are specified in legends and the first item in the second column will not be placed in a row with the title, if the title method is used, and will be in a row with the first label in the first column. Is there any way to cure it automatically? How?
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D


plt.plot([], [], linestyle='--', color='black', label='Dashed Line')
plt.plot([], [], linestyle=':', color='black', label='Dotted Line')
plt.plot([], [], linestyle='-', linewidth=2, color='black', label='Double Solid Line')
plt.plot([], [], linestyle='-.', color='black', label='Dash-Dot Line')

legend_ETP = Line2D([0], [0], marker='o', c='k', ls='None', markerfacecolor='k', markersize=8, label="Far")
legend_IOTP = Line2D([0], [0], marker='s', c='k', ls='None', markerfacecolor='k', markersize=8, label="Near")
legend_void = Line2D([0], [0], marker='', ls='None', label="")

ELS_handles, ELS_labels = plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()

Dw_leg = 'Exact = 0.5'

new_handles = [legend_ETP] + [legend_IOTP] + ELS_handles
new_labels = ["Far"] + ["Near"] + ELS_labels
legend = plt.legend(handles=new_handles, labels=new_labels, fontsize=12, loc='lower left', ncol=2, title=Dw_leg)
legend._legend_box.align = "left"

# new_handles = [legend_void] + [legend_ETP] + [legend_IOTP] + ELS_handles
# new_labels = [Dw_leg] + ["Far"] + ["Near"] + ELS_labels
# legend = plt.legend(handles=new_handles, labels=new_labels, fontsize=12, loc='lower left', ncol=2)

plt.show()



I wonder if you could adapt this answer.

Thank you @RuthC, it will solve the problem (I did). You can put your answer based on that, satisfying the need for this question for future readers.

Glad you solved it!  If you have figured out the details, I think it is fine to post and accept your own answer.
